# How to configure SSL encryption in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I want to enable the SSL encryption on SQL Server but I am facing the issues on **step 8.**

Which certificate how have to request?

How can I get the certificate?

Ref link: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3299/how-to-configure-ssl-encryption-in-sql-server/

1.Open the Microsoft Management Console (MMC): click Start, then click Run and in the Run dialog box type: MMC

2.On the File menu, click Add/Remove Snap-in...

3.Select Certificates, click Add.

4.You are prompted to open the snap-in for your user account, the service 
account, or the computer account. Select the Computer Account.

5.Select Local computer, and then click Finish.

6.Click OK in the Add/Remove Snap-in dialog box.

7.Click to select the Personal folder in the left-hand pane.

8.Right-click in the right-hand pane, point to All Tasks, and then click 
**Request New Certificate...**

9.Click Next in the Certificate Request Wizard dialog box. Select certificate type 'Computer'.

10.You can enter a friendly name in text box if you want or leave it blank, then complete the wizard.

11.Now you should see the certificate in the folder with the fully qualified computer domain name.

Comment: Any specific error? there might be an access limitation which prevent to access certificate authority server. It would be fine If you use default certificate exist on the server.

Comment: There is no specific error. when I click on Request New Certificate it show blank box. How can I add the certificate or we have to buy any certificate? which certificate I have to buy? I am the admin of the server

Comment: If you already have default certificate than It will be sql service account doesn't have access to it.

Comment: I am the admin of server and SQL server both.

Comment: Please let me know the certificate name, I have to add.

Comment: Certificate name would be your Server name, refer Certificates (Local Computer) -> Personal -> Certificates -> <Server name>

Comment: I found blank. popup. no certificate visible.

Comment: Goto above location and try right click on certificate -> All tasks -> Manage Private Keys....assign sql server service account permissions and restart SQL services.

Comment: No option for Manage private key only available below option: find certificate,import,request new certificate